# Как передать в сервис объект Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Есть такой сервис, которому передается объект `globalScope`:

```
.service('socketChat', function(globalScope){
    this.listenSocket = function(socket, cb){
    })
});
```

Когда вызываю метод из сервиса:

```
socketChat.listenSocket(Socket, function(data) {
      alert('test');
});
```

Как при каждом обращении к сервису передавать в него объект `globalScope` так чтобы он был доступен внутри методов сервиса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понятен вопрос. При использовании инжектора в методах сервиса globalScope будет доступен, например, так:

```
.factory('socketChat', function(globalScope){
        var self = this;
        var self.globalScope = globalScope;

        return {
            listenSocket: function(socket, cb){
                alert(self.globalScope.text);
            }
    })
});
```

Если, вы, просто хотите передать объект в сервис, можно сделать так:

```
.factory('socketChat', function(){
        var self = this;
        var self.globalScope;

        return {
            setGlobalScope: function (globalScope) {
                return self.globalScope = globalScope;
            },
            getGlobalScope: function () {
                return self.globalScope;
            },
            listenSocket: function(socket, cb){
                if(Socket){
                   cb();
                }
            }
    })
});
...
socketChat.setGlobalScope(globalScope);
socketChat.listenSocket(Socket, function(){
  });
```

Использовать единый globalScope в функции, передаваемой в качестве аргумента метода сервиса:

```
socketChat.listenSocket(Socket, function(data) {
      var gs = socketChat.getGlobalScope();
      gs.text = 'new text';
      socketChat.setGlobalScope(gs);
});
```